# ImageMagick dashed rectangle incorrectly rendered

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

When trying to draw a dashed rectangle with ImageMagick using the following command:

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:skyblue -fill white -stroke black \
-draw "stroke-width 3 stroke-dasharray 10 10 rectangle 50,50 250,250" draw_rect.gif
```

I get the following image, clearly wrong (note the "z" shapes):

[image]

No matter what I try (it happens also with paths, with different line caps and joins, stroke widths, dash arrays, colors, transparent fill,...) I get these strange artifacts.

Version is `ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 aarch64 2021-02-02` (ARM), but I tried also with an x86 server `ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2021-02-03` and got the same result.

Is this an ImageMagick limitation? a bug? If so, I can't believe a library so mature could behave so weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IM 6.9.12.73, I get the following result with your following command.

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:skyblue -fill white -stroke black -draw "stroke-width 3 stroke-dasharray 10 10 rectangle 50,50 250,250" draw_rect.gif
```

[image]

Likely, your old version of Imagemagick had a bug. You should upgrade if you can.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42! Pitty that's the latest version in Amazon Linux 2 repositories, so upgrading the server would require a more time consuming path (afaik).

Comment: What about downgrading?  Perhaps it was just a bug in that version?

Comment: Is an option, but maybe the older version introduces new bugs. I will stay with the current version and avoid dashes in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to compile your IM version on my Mac, but got compile errors. Sorry I cannot test that version.